Relative Date Filters - Other options besides 'LAST WEEK' , 'THIS MONTH' etc
I am aware of the relative filters such as 'LAST WEEK', 'THIS MONTH' etc, but I am looking to pull data for 1/2/3/4 weeks in advance and the same in the past - At the moment I am having to manually update the dates for 2 weeks and 3 weeks but can automate the 1 week and 1 month time periods. Is there anything I can do to automate the full process here? Any suggestions or comments are welcomed - thank you!

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include more detail about your use case.  I'm not clear what date you mean, what the date range means, and why you are updating the dates.  Screenshots can be helpful.

see SOQL doc on date literals
